# Why this thumbnail hard crop code does not work?

Tags: rss, thumbnails, images

I am trying to show thumbnail image as an attachment in the feed. So I use following code.

```
function add_images_to_rss($var) {
    global $post;
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {     
        $tid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID);
        //$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($tid, 'large');      
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($tid, '100x100');  
        $thumb_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($tid);
        $up = wp_upload_dir();
        print '<enclosure type="'.get_post_mime_type($tid).'" length="'.filesize($up['basedir'].'/'.$thumb_meta['file']).'" url="'.$thumb[0].'" />';
    }
}
add_action('rss2_item','add_images_to_rss');
```

But it shows larger size images as attachment.
It suppose to show 100x100 size attachments only.
What I am doing wrong ?

How can I show 100x100 image size attachemnts in that feed?

site is : http://www.supgower.com/feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the size parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` in a wrong format. This parameter can be:

- A string: keyword of the image size; thumbnail, medium, large, full or any other custom size previously registered).
- A 2-items array representing the width and height; for example, `array( 100, 100 )`.

So, you have to change this:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($tid, '100x100');
```

With:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $tid, array(100,100) );
```

And this should also work for thumbnail size:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $tid, 'thumbnail' );
```